# Having trouble with code to find average of an array of 10 random whole numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Not sure if this is how I should post the problem I'm having - please give me pointers if so. Don't want to get it closed, so I will do my best. The task is to write code that finds the average of an array of 10 random whole numbers between 1-100. I've managed to get together some code to create an array of 10 random whole numbers between 1-100, which works. Next I got some code to find the average of a specified array of numbers, which also works. However, when I try to use that code to the find the average of the array of 10 random whole numbers between 1-100, it runs but gives an individual average for each number - not quite sure how it even calculates that. Hope someone can take a look and help me adjust the code so that it runs right.

Here is the code to create an array of 10 random whole numbers between 1-100 :

```
package Array.codejava;

import java.util.Random;

public class Array2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // range
          int max = 100;
          int min = 1;
          
          int[] list = new int[10];

            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
              int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
              list[i] = randomNumber;
```

The code I have for finding an average of a specified array of numbers is -

```
package Array.codejava;

public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double score[] = {96, 92, 81, 54, 58, 13, 81, 6, 48, 67};
        int i, sum, avg;
        sum = 0;
        for(i=0; i<score.length; i++) {
            sum +=score[i];
        }
            
        avg = sum /score.length;
        System.out.println("The average of given Score:" +avg);

    }

}
```

Next when I combine the code (tried to adjust and make it work right), I get that problem I explained.

```
package Array.codejava;

import java.util.Random;

public class Array2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // range
          int max = 100;
          int min = 1;
          
          int[] list = new int[10];

            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
              int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
              list[i] = randomNumber;
        
        // create instance of Random class
          Random randomNum = new Random();
          int random = min + randomNum.nextInt(max);
          System.out.println(random);
          
        // average
          int i1, sum, avg;
            sum = 0;
            for(i1=0; i1<list.length; i1++) {
                sum +=list[i1];
            }
                
            avg = sum /list.length;
            System.out.println("The average of given list:" +avg);
          
        }}}
```

Hope someone is able to help with this.

Comment: your first loop should have a closing brace after `list[i] = randomNumber;` I highly suggest using an IDE which autoformats your code, then you would've seen that there is a missplacement

Comment: Lino - when I do this I get an error to take out a closing brace in the end of the code. When I run this makes the program generate one number and average of the list as opposed to ten numbers and average of the list for each number. Still don't understand why it gives average of the list for each number individually or how to make it so that it gives the total average.

Comment: Also my IDE does autoformat the code (I think). I use Eclipse and it shows errors that you can click on and see autoformat options (if that's what autoformat is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to return an `int[]` populated with random integers and another function to return the average of these integers. I also recommend you use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) to get an `int` value between `origin` (inclusive) and `bound` (exclusive) so that you do not have to cast the generated random number.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test

        // Five random integers and their average
        int[] list = getRandomNums(5);
        System.out.println("Average of " + Arrays.toString(list) + ": " + getAverage(list));

        // Ten random integers and their average
        list = getRandomNums(10);
        System.out.println("Average of " + Arrays.toString(list) + ": " + getAverage(list));
    }

    static int[] getRandomNums(int n) {
        int[] list = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
        }
        return list;
    }

    static double getAverage(int[] list) {
        return Arrays.stream(list).average().getAsDouble();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Average of [32, 22, 91, 48, 95]: 57.6
Average of [48, 33, 39, 22, 55, 11, 66, 58, 45, 23]: 40.0
```

Note that your code, `(int) (Math.random() * 100)` returns an `int` from `0` to `99`, not from `1` to `100`. If at all, you want to use `Math.random()`, you should use `(int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1)`.

Comment: Your code works, but how do I get it to do the average as integers and not floating numbers? I tried changing double to int and getAsDouble to getAsInt but I get the error that method getAsInt is not defined for type OptionalDouble. It says to rename it but I don't know to what.

I think my Math.random() code works because I said the int max to 100 and int min to 1. Otherwise I see I should do what you say, because of index values.

Comment: @JavaNub - You need to change the definition as `static int getAverage(int[] list) {
  return (int) Arrays.stream(list).average().getAsDouble();
 }` in order to get the average as an `int`. Feel free to comment in case of any other doubt/issue.

Comment: Thank you. What's the reason for the parenthesis in (int) there? I get a bunch of markers without it and I'm trying to learn concepts. And why is it getAsDouble if we're returning an integer?

Comment: @JavaNub - You are most welcome. The `(int)` part in `(int) Arrays.stream(list).average().getAsDouble()` is called casting i.e. you are casting the result returned bt `Arrays.stream(list).average().getAsDouble()` to an `int`. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html to learn more about it.

Comment: That's the other part I don't get is why we use getAsDouble if we are getting an integer. Usually can't mix double with int, so what makes it work here/how do we know when to

Comment: @JavaNub - [`Arrays.stream(int[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) returns an `IntStream` and [`IntStream#average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--) returns an [OptionalDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) which does not have a method to return the average as an `int`.